# Iterate until encountering the value has the fractional part 0

Tags: c, iteration

I am writing a program (in order to exercise and practice) that counts the number of elements in an array until encountering the value has the fractional part 0 **without the usage of any integer counter variables.**

I have done it below with the use of integer counter (which is 'i', BTW), but I cannot figure out a way without using 'i' in a loop. How can I do it without integer counter?

Input:

```
5
1.2
-3.4
5.00
4
5.45
```

Output:
Before the first integer: 2 elements

```
void int_or_float(float arr[], int n){
    int i, j;
    int counter = 0;
    char str[10];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
        sprintf(str, "%f", arr[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            printf("%c\n", str[j]);
            if (str[j] == '.' && str[j + 1] == '0'){
                printf("Aborted!");
                printf("\n\nBefore the first integer: %d elements", i);
                j = 11;
                i = n + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, i;
    float *things;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    things = malloc (n * sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%f", &things[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    int_or_float(things, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: technically, aren't `i` and `j` "integer counter values"? and more technically, `5` is the same as `5.00`, since you're forcing everything to be floats.

Comment: 5 is used for allocating memory, it is not an element of array.

Comment: why you don't want to use `i` .i think its fine to use...

Comment: What will happen for "5.01"?

Comment: Also when you scan it as a `%f` and do a `fscanf(str,`%f`,arr[i])` all the values will be like `5.000000` and so on.... So what is the fraction part you are talking about?

Comment: Do you know the binary representation of floating point numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP did require a solution **without the usage of any integer counter variables**. How can you count anything without using a counter? By advancing through the array with a pointer, but that will only work if you include a sentinel so you can terminate. Let's say this sentinel is some negative number.

In `main())` you'll need an extra element for the sentinel.

In `int_or_float()` you can then step through the array with a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void int_or_float(float arr[]) {    // removed int n
    float *ptr = arr;
    int ival;
    while (*ptr >= 0) {
        printf("%f\n", *ptr);
        ival = (int)*ptr;
        if (*ptr == (float)ival) {
            printf("Aborted!");
            printf("\n\nBefore the first integer: %d elements", ptr - arr);
            return;
            }
        ptr++;
        }
    printf("\n\nNo integer values found");
    }

int main() {
    int n, i;
    float *things;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    things = malloc ((n+1) * sizeof(float));  // extra for sentinel
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%f", &things[i]);
    }
    things[i] = -1;         // sentinel
    printf("\n");
    int_or_float(things);   // n removed
    free (things);          // remember to free memory
    return 0;
}
```

It must be pointed out that not all integers *can* be exactly represented in floating point.

You should also check the return values from `malloc()` and `scanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use this?

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if(round(arr[i])==arr[i])
    {
        printf("Before the first integer: %d elements\n",  i);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the point of doing so, but it would be possible to do it this way without i:

```
void int_or_float(const float *arr, int n){
    int j;
    float counter = 0.0f;
    char str[10];
    while(n-- >0){
        printf("%f\n", *arr);
        sprintf(str, "%f", *arr++);
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            printf("%c\n", str[j]);
            if (str[j] == '.' && str[j + 1] == '0'){
                printf("Aborted!");
                printf("\n\nBefore the first integer: %f elements\n", counter);
                j = 11;
                n=0;
            }
        }
        counter = counter+1.0f;
    }
}
```